# L298N motor driver output error

Tags: dc-motor, driver, h-bridge, motor-controller

I had worked previously on a project which used a L298N motor driver to control motors.[Datasheet Link](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf).

I have now completed my project and started with the production phase of it. But while I was successful in dispatching the first lot perfectly fine, the second lot is giving a lot of issues. And the issues are:

When I am giving 0 and 5 V to turn my motors in one direction, instead of giving +Vcc and ground voltage, it is giving me +Vcc and 3 V. I am getting really confused about why 3 V is coming when it should have been 0 V. And this is not only with one driver, but many of the drivers are also doing the same. And if I change Drivers by desoldering and again soldering, I sometimes work, or either I have to again replace the driver until I get the correct output. I am doubtful If my circuit is wrong because my first lot have been dispatched without issues.

Can the lot of my L289N be wrong? I am attaching my circuit too below:[image: My circuit.] At sense pin is a connected a 470 mohm resistor to ground.

Also attaching the internals on L298n from datasheet[image]

Comment: What is the load? And what controls the L298N? Where did you source the L298N?

Comment: The L298 is a horrible part with huge losses, that will show up as its low output being well above ground and its high output being well below the motor supply.  This is fundamental to Darlington  topology,  you should re-design with an FET bridge.  Your oversized sense resistor makes things worse, too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't see any sense resistors in that schematic!

Comment: @TimWescott the sense resistors are described in the text.  If they were really missing (nothing completing the path to ground) the chip wouldn't be able to drive low at all.

Comment: Measuring the voltage on the sense resistor would be a good diagnostic though; and using a power resistor as a load in place of a motor.  But again, this chip is a bad choice.   Another thing, the naming of the supply net as VBOOST is highly suspicious **one generally doesn't want to drive a motor from a boost converter**.